# Using charts ASP.net - Y Axis as count of values on X Axis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to make a chart which will show career sectors on the X Axis, and the most popular of these on the Y Axis. Every time someone selects a career sector on my web app, it is recorded in the Career Activity table of my database. Essentially what I want to do is to show the number of times each sector has been selected on my Y Axis. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Career1" YValueMembers=""
                            IsValueShownAsLabel="false" ChartArea="ChartArea1"
                            MarkerBorderColor="#DBDBDB">
                        </asp:Series>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code sample to generate a chart. 
Here data points will be based on your data source.

You can get the count for each sector by using count statement group by sector.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1">
                        <points>
                            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Sector 1" YValues="32" Label="32" />
                            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Sector 2" YValues="56" Label="56"/>
                            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Sector 3" YValues="35" Label="35"/>
                            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Sector 4" YValues="12" Label="12"/>
                            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Sector 5" YValues="35" Label="35"/>
                        </points>
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```